# Battery Level From Terminal

Tags: ios

Is there a way to get an iOS device battery level from terminal when it's plugged into the computer? I've looked into ioreg and that only displays my macbook's battery.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get this information as recently as macOS 10.14.2 using the `libimobiledevice` formula from Homebrew. You may need to use the most recent version of the library, hence the `--HEAD` appended to the install command:

```
$ brew install --HEAD libimobiledevice
```

After that, try these commands:

```
$ idevice_id --list
<UDID>

$ ideviceinfo -u <UDID> --simple
DeviceName: foo's phone
HardwareModel: D22AP
ProductName: iPhone OS
ProductType: iPhone10,3
ProductVersion: 12.0

$ ideviceinfo -u <UDID> --domain com.apple.mobile.battery
BatteryCurrentCapacity: 43
BatteryIsCharging: true
ExternalChargeCapable: true
ExternalConnected: true
FullyCharged: false
GasGaugeCapability: true
HasBattery: true
```

More information is available. Try `ideviceinfo --help` to list the additional domains you can query.

Comment: And you can also run `idevicediagnostics diagnostics` to get the detailed battery information.

Comment: Is there a way to get the charging power (watts)?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command "cfgutil get batteryCurrentCapacity", you can get cfgutil by installing the command line tools for Apple Configurator.

Comment: This doesn't work unless the phone is physically connected via USB unfortunately. Also, the command takes a _long_ time to complete (about 6 seconds on my system). I know this information is exposed somehow via WiFi (iTunes Sync protocol) because it shows up in [coconutBattery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/#idSCR). Anyone know how this is done?

Comment: @luckman212 were you ever able to figure out how to get battery level wirelessly?

Comment: You can use [https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy], once a device is linked to xcode over wifi/ethernet. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc]

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this might be doable via SSH

http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SSH_Over_USB

Then with this command:

https://github.com/magn2o/iOS-Battery-Status

Comment: Please post the commands in the answer so that if the links break, the answer stays.